# What is the cross-referencing source code in plain.tex?

Tags: macros, tex-core, plain-tex

I'm doing macro programming, and I would like to know what is the cross-referencing source code in `plain.tex`, so that I can apply those source codes to my own .sty file. If anybody can give me some hints about it that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know there is no direct support for cross-references in Plain TeX if not other macro bundles are included.

Comment: plain tex has almost no automatic numbering the section headings and list commands use explicit numbers so there is little need for mechanised cross refs, to refer to section 2 just type  "section 2"

Comment: there *is* cross-referencing applied in *the texbook*.  it's very different from what's defined in latex.  the definitions are in the file `manmac.tex`, which is present in tex live in the directory `.../tex/plain/knuth-lib/`.  look for `\xref`,

Answer (score 5):

plain tex has almost no automatic numbering the section headings and list commands use explicit numbers so there is little need for mechanised cross refs, to refer to section 2 just type "section 2"

Of course macro packages built on plain may define a cross reference mechanism. Barbara mentions manmac, as used for the TeXBook sources, also eplain defines a cross reference mechanism similar to LaTeX's `\ref` system, see section 4.9 of the eplain manual.